# Angular and RxJS imports

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, webstorm, rxjs5

I've always known to import my `Observable` operators separately to limit the load times. However I've noticed something today that I hope someone could please explain to me.

I am using IntelliJ/WebStorm with Webpack.

Let's say on a page in my `ngOnInit` I have an http call:

```
 ngOnInit() {  
        this.http.get('https//:google.com').map(e => e);
 }
```

If I don't import the map operator the compiler will complain, so I import it like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

All is good in the world. Until I need to use an Observable. So, I'll add one.

```
 ngOnInit() {
        let test = Observable.create(subscriber => {
            return null;
        });

        this.http.get('https//:google.com').map(e => e);
 }
```

Now the compiler understandably complains that it cannot find Observable, so I get IntelliJ/WebStorm to import it for me and adds this at the top of my file:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
```

All is good again. But, this new import seems to make the map import irrelevant. What I mean is that, if I remove the map import and just leave the Observable one in, all compiles fine...

However, if I specify to import Observable like this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Then I must re-add the import for the map operator...

Am I importing all of RxJS when I import my Observable like this?

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
```

If so, how can I tell IntelliJ to not do that and import class only?

Comment: That is correct. If you import `Observable` from `rxjs` you will import **all** rxjs operators and functions (where among map) which is quite bad since it increases the file size. 

I have no idea if you can tell InteliJ to be more specific for the auto imports.

Comment: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs'` will import `Rx.d.ts` (check out the content in it ;) ) which is **everything**. You need to import it like this: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';`. The problem is not what you 'import' to your scope (between the curly braces), but the file and recursively all imports what takes a lot of transpilation time we don't want.

Comment: Thanks tjoskar and Aitch, this is clear now.

Answer (score 14):

Why not have a file(ex: rxjs-extensions.ts) with your required rxjs observable class extensions and operators?

```
// Observable class extensions
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// Observable operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

And then in your main module (ex app.module.ts) import from this file:

```
import './rxjs-extensions';
```

And in your main component (ex: app.component.ts) just import Observavle:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

This is how it is covered on the main angular tutorial.

Comment: I failed to mention in my question that I had tried this. So although it could help someone else I had done this before. I was just not clear if the ...from 'rxjs'; imported the whole thing, which is turns out it does.. Thanks for your reply though

Answer (score 1):

Starting from WebStorm 2016.3 (I believe), you have an option to blacklist certain imports. `Editor > Code Style > StypeScript`

```
Do not import exactly from: [rxjs]
```

Additionally, there is a flag available in tslint to prohibit global imports:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "import-blacklist": [true, "rxjs"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use all operators by using this:

```
import * as Rx from "rxjs/Rx";

Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: as mentioned in the angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#enable-rxjs-operators to keep the size as small as possible you should only import what you use.