# How to import RXJS types for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, rxjs

If I understand correctly, `rxjs` (version 5) is written in typescript and is packaged with all the definitions.

I tried using them, but I cannot seem to find a way to do that. I get the error

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Observable'

Here is my `tsconfg.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

and the file I try to compile

```
const { Observable } = require("@reactivex/rxjs")

function timer(time: Number): Observable {
  return Observable.timer(time)
}
```

I run `node_modules/.bin/tsc test.ts`

Am I missing some typescript config here? Is there something to do to enable types?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The typescript definitions for `Observable` `Subject` etc from RXJS are bundled and installed with the RXJS package. So if you run `npm install rxjs` you will get the type description files (*.td) included in the npm module.

In this case I think your issue is with the import of the `Observable` module. It should read:

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

Comment: From my current investigation, the combination of `"module":"commonjs"` in the `tsconfig.json` file and, as you say, `import` instead of `require` seems to work... But I still have no idea why?!

Comment: @atomrc if it is the correct answer then please mark it as so. If you are using Typescript I would just stick to `import`, good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651495/difference-between-import-from-and-import-require-in-typescript

Comment: Your answer, alone, is not the entire solution to my problem. There are still things I need to understand about the `"module": "commonjs"` config I think. It seems counterintuitive to use `import` on one side and `commonjs` in the config ...

Comment: @atomrc that may be true but then you need to ask that question specifically, and don't be surprised if it gets removed with 'needs to do more research'. I provided you a good starting point.

Comment: I am not sure how can I accept an answer that doesn't solve my problem. future visitors that might have the same problem will try your answer and it won't solve their problem either

Comment: That is a laudable aim, except your question has now changed, and you seem to need general research on the difference between import and require in a Typescript context. Perhaps ask a new question (unless it's a dupe) with that topic? There are better examples of this questionl, e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751826/angular-and-rxjs-imports 

Anyway, I think you might need to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour I just did for the first time today myself!

Comment: Ok I know what is happening: in my different tests I added a `"module": "es2015"` in my tsconfig that didn't appeared in my initial question. That is why your answer didn't work, sorry about that. This is why I needed to change this config to `"modules": "commonjs"` for your answer to work

Comment: ah ok I was ignoring that part, as I haven't fiddled with tsconfig much myself.

Comment: Now I need to find out why `"module": "es2015"` doesn't work, but that's indeed another question :) Thanks again and sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 3):

Can be due to the bug in version RxJS version 7.4.0.
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/6641

Comment: I'm not sure how that 2021 bug was relevant for RxJS5 some 4 years ago in 2017