# Why does the IDE see rxjs types as any

Tags: typescript, rxjs, webstorm, rxjs7

All I did was just install rxjs with `npm i rxjs`

Every time I wrote a `Behavior`... and pressed `tab`, the IDE would import the `BehaviorSubject` type from the `"rxjs/dist/types"` directory. And this is a bare type that does not have any execution logic.

To make the code work, you need to import the class with the code - just from `"rxjs"`, but then another problem. The IDE thinks that all types from there are `any`.
If you return subject from the function, the function will say that it returns `any`.

If you explicitly set the type of any variable, it will also say that it is `any`.

**P.S.**
I use WebStorm

[image]

Comment: I use rxjs with "^7.5.6" ver.

Answer (score 1):

What IDE are you using?

You might find an answer here?
[How to import RXJS types for TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747323/how-to-import-rxjs-types-for-typescript)

Seems to work for me in VSCode

`import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';`
[image]

Comment: i use  WebStorm /

Comment: `import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs/dist/types/internal/BehaviorSubject";`
`const b: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1)` 

such code doesn't work too ;c 
it has correct type, but it's bare type