# Why do some js codes use Rx. prefix with Reactive Extension, but Angular world does not?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Why do some js codes use `Rx.` prefix with Reactive Extension, but Angular world does not use it?

I first know Reactive Extension in Angular world. When using Observable object, I don't need to use `Rx.`.
But many tutorials online about Reactive Extension always use `Rx.` prefix.
Sometimes, a method in that tutorial can't be used in Angular world, like the class level `catch` method:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.catch(
  get('url1'),
  get('url2'),
  get('url3'),
  getCachedVersion()
);
```

What's the relationship between those two situations?

**Update:**
In my Angular project,
I can import the entire library using `import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';`. (not `import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';`)

Comment: RxJS can be imported in a number of ways. The docs should answer your question: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/installation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';`
you are importing the entire core set of functionality.

when using `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';` 
you are importing only Observable functionality.

It really depends on what you really wnat to use.

You can do a catch in a observable.
Imagine you have a function

```
public getY():number{
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) new Error('ee'); 
  else 
   return 4;
}
```

Then you can catch an error like this:

```
let obs = Observable.of(this.getY()).catch((e) => { return Promise.reject(e);});
obs.subscribe((d)=>{console.log(d)});
```

Comment: I can't use `import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'` in my angular project. package.json file include "rxjs": "5.2.0" item.

Comment: @niaomingjian you might have to do _import * as Rx  from 'rxjs/Rx';_ I would suggest having a look at https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs

Comment: [The tutorial](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html#catching-errors) says we can use  the class level `catch` method to catch errors. How can I use it in angular? I know how to use the instance level `catch` method in angular, but not the class level one.

Answer (score 1):

The `Rx` prefix is used typically only in scenarios where you include the RxJS package using the `<script>` tag. Then everything is under `Rx` namespace.

This isn't necessary when using with TypeScript or in Node environment.

Comment: How can I use `Rx.Observable.catch` static method in angular?

Comment: You import it and then use it in a chain like `source.catch()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751826/angular-and-rxjs-imports

Comment: I can use instance method `catch`, but can't use static method `catch`.

Comment: Because there's no static `Observable.catch`. It's an operator that needs to be used inside a chain

Comment: [This tutorial](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html#catching-errors) says it's a class level method. So I think there's a static method `catch`.

Comment: I don't know what version of RxJS the tutorial uses but if you have a look at the RxJS 5 documentation you won't find it under static methods: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html